# 6 Character Short Hash Algorithm

Tags: c#, hash, md5, sha

My goal is to generate a short Hash string of 6 characters (possibly containing characters [A-Z][a-z][0-9]) for a string which is 42 case-insensitive alphanumeric characters in length. Uniqueness is the key requirement. Security or performance is not so important.

Is there a specific algorithm which will give this result or should I stick to truncating a MD5 Hash or a SHA-1 Hash ([Like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826403/hash-algorithm-with-alphanumeric-output-of-20-characters-max))? If so, what is the probability of a collision?

Comment: I tried this,   

string sourceString = "SomeTestStringWhichIs42CharactersInLength!";         Console.WriteLine(sourceString.GetHashCode().ToString("X6"));

It returns an 8 Character Hash.

Comment: How can you generate a unique 6 chars hash for a 42 chars long string?

Comment: With your limits, you can (at best) hash 62^6 numbers without collision. Although after hashing half that many, you'll have a 50% chance of collision (at best). Depends on the data to hash and the hashing algorithm - of course. Some algorithms will do better with different sets of data

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your best bet would be the truncating well-known hash function (MD5 or SHA-family) because these algorithms have statistically good uniform distributions of the hash values (and also using full hash and not just 6 chars there).

Now some calculations for probability of collision

```
- Number of letters in English alphabet: 26
- Add capitals: 26
- Add numerics: 10
--------------

In total you get 26 + 26 + 10 = 62 characters. 

Now you have 6 places, which gives you 62^6 possible combinations.
That is 56.800.235.584 ~ 57 billion combinations. 
This is a space of possible hash values - N.
--------------
To compute collisions let's use the formula 

Pcollision = K^2 / 2N

Which is a very rough approximation of collision probability
```

Now let's see the result table for a number of items in a table - K

```
# items     | Probability of collision
---------------------------------------
10          |  1.7 * 10^-9
100         |  1.7 * 10^-7
1K          |  1.7 * 10^-5
10K         |  1.7 * 10^-3
100K        |  0.17
```

This formula can only be used for small K, but it shows that given 100K entries in the hash table you would roughly have 17% chance of collision.

#### Links

[Collision probability](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities)

Comment: Thanks for your instructive comment. But I think you calculated `Pcollision = K^2 / N` in your table rather than `Pcollision = K^2 / 2N`?

Comment: Are there mathematical proofs that these truncated forms of the hash algorithms have the same qualities as the full version?

Answer (score 11):

Easy hash :)

```
private string Hash(string str)
{
    var allowedSymbols = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
    var hash = new char[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        hash[i % 6] = (char)(hash[i % 6] ^ str[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        hash[i] = allowedSymbols[hash[i] % allowedSymbols.Length];
    }

    return new string(hash);
}
```

Comment: This algorithm has a high collision rate due to the XOR here `hash[i % 6] ^ str[i]`. OP states that the input string is case-insensative, for both a-z and A-Z the highest two bits are the same for all characters. Even if you used all the normal printable ASCII characters (0x20-0x7e) the top two bits are still identical for 66% of the character set.

Comment: Fits Perfectly for me. I had to generate a color based on an name and an degree of nested elements. https://jsfiddle.net/fgg8xx2k/ example is written in Typescript

Comment: I found this function is very useful for my use, but it does have a problem of high collision rate. My solution is use to MD5 to hash my str first, and then use this function to get a user friendly output. It seems to resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is almost certainly to use SHA1, convert to Base62 (although Base64 would be much easier as it's built in to the framework [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx). You'll have to do some looking for a decent Base62 library), and then truncate the output to 6 bytes.

I would not use `GetHashCode()` as it has a [history of collision problems](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/519104/string-gethashcode-ignores-any-characters-in-the-string-beyond-the-first-null-byte-in-x64-runtime). (I'm not trying to claim that this specific bug would apply to you, only mentioning this as evidence that `GetHashCode` hasn't been implemented well in the past.)

I also would not implement a custom hashing algorithm, it's extremely easy to accidentally write an algorithm with a high collision rate. A lot of research and scrutiny has gone in to SHA1 and the other major hashing algorithms, and you'd be very hard pressed to come up with anything better.